# Mongoose Schema Getter

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongoose and MongoDB, and I'd like to understand the following code a little more:

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            get: (): undefined => undefined
        }
    },
    {
        toJSON: {
            getters: true
        }
    }
);
```

What does the line `get: (): undefined => undefined` mean?
And what is the purpose of adding `toJSON: { getters: true }`? I'm assuming they are to enable getters, but I'd like to know more in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have a user schema.

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      get: toUpper
    }
  },
  { toJSON: { getters: true } } // if this is false, toUpper getter will not execute
)

function toUpper(name: string) {
  return name.toUpperCase()
}

const User = model('user', userSchema)

export default User
```

Let's assume you want to change the name property to uppercase every time, so you will define the toUpper getter function and set this to `get`.

Now if you have not enabled `{ toJSON: { getters: true } }`, the toUpper getter function will never execute, and the name property will never be transformed to uppercase.

Now comes your question,
if you've set `get: (): undefined => undefined` and `{ toJSON: { getters: true } }` means it will execute the getter function and return undefined instead of a password, hence password key will be removed from the result.

I hope this helps you to understand the getters.

References [Getters Setters](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html), [toJSON options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find out, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad. It was useful information!